# passing variables from dynamic table

Tags: php, html, sql-server, forms, variables

Good morning,
I was searching, but couldn't find answer :(
I have a table created dynamically with data taken from MSSQL:

```
$tabelka = '
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<table border =1 width=40% class="hoverTable"><tr>
<td width=10%><B>Biuro</B></td>
<td width=10%><b>Drukarka</b></td>
<td width=20%><b>Toner</b></td>
<td width=10%><b>Na stanie</b></td>
<td width=10%><b>Zamówionych</b></td>
<td width=10%><b>Akcja</b></td></tr>';

$sql = 'select * from raportTonerow';
if ($result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {

$tabelka .= '
<tr><td width=10%>'.$row['kodBiura'].'</td>
    <td width=10%>'.$row['nazwaDrukarki'].'</td>
    <td width=20%>'.$row['toner'].'</td>
    <td width=10%>
    <input type="number" name="naStanie" size=10% maxlength=1 value="'.$row['naStanie'].'"></td>
    <td width=10%><input type="number" name="zamowionych" size=10% maxlength=1 value="'.$row['zamowionych'].'"></td>
    <td width=10%><input type="submit" value="Aktualizuj" name="akt"></td>';
    }
}
    $tabelka .= '</form></table>';
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['akt'])) {
echo "test ".$_POST['zamowionych'];
```

}

it is showing me only last data from table. How can I pass variables from each row? 
What I want to have is: when user click on button on the row only data from that row will be send in form.

thank you
Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))

{

?>

<td> <?php echo $row->kodBiura;?></td>

<td> <?php echo $row->nazwaDrukarki; ?></td>

<td> <?php echo $row->toner; ?></td>


<?php  }?>
```